# Why PermGen is not populated faster?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, permgen

I want to invoke `OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` error as soon as possible.

I have created custom classloader:

```
public class MyClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

private MyClassLoader(URL[] urls) {
    super(urls);
}

@Override
public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if (name.equals("com.memory.leaks.Leak")) {
        return findClass(name);
    }

    return super.loadClass(name);
}

static IStructure newInstance() {

    try {
        final URL classSource = Structure.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();

        try (URLClassLoader cl = new MyClassLoader(new URL[] { classSource })) { 
            return (ILeak) cl.loadClass("com.memory.leaks.Leak").newInstance();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

}
```

and here is a `Leak` class loaded by this classloader:

```
package com.memory.leaks;

public class Leak  {

}
```

This code will cause OOME already. 
Then I modified `Leak` class by adding 20 methods with very long names to it:

```
public void aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa ...~ 50 chars... aaaaaaaa () {
}
```

Since method names reside in PermGen, such a modification should speed up populating PermGen. However, dynamic analysis (using JVisualVM with VisualGC) shows that it is being done with virtually the same speed:

Before modification (71s):

[image: Before modification]

After modification  (69s):

[image: After modification]

My question is simple: Why?

Comment: WHich Java version is that? FWIW, Orcle's JRE (8+) has no permgen anymore

Comment: It was Oracle JRE 1.7. I am aware that PermGen was replaced by Metaspace in JRE 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would having a method with a long name significantly increase the amount of space used by a class? The class loader will intern the method name, notice that the string already exists in memory and use that string rather than a new string.

If you want to increase the amount of space a class takes up then declare lots of static fields.

Comment: I totally forgot that static fields reside in PermGen, too. Thanks!